# Updating global arrays in R using recursion in parallel

Tags: arrays, r, recursion, parallel-processing

I am attempting to convert my C++ code using recursion and OpenMP in this open Google Doc [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/19wTibAwDQTA2nJjZdOCKg6yD32Z6dU6GsQ1tJRzuzQ4/pub) to R using recursion and the parallel and/or doParallel package(s).

My trouble arises in the use of the global variable arrays in C++ being passed in as an argument (`double* p`) to the recursive function.  I believe that R is not capable of this using any of the parallel packages?  If this is true, I need to be able to create the four arrays in the recursive function, fill them simultaneously, and then return them.  Is this possible?  Could one use the `exists()` function to check to see if the variables had been created and initialized?  I've had troubles doing this so far.

I believe that this return (after the arrays are filled) could be easily accomplished using the `foreach` and `%dopar%` structure.

In summary, I'm having trouble getting the arrays to fill and then being able to return them outside of the recursive function.  The recursive function that I used in C++ was able to get away without returning a value since it was filling the global arrays via recursion and OpenMP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: R's `parallel` package uses forks (in which case the global variable is read-only) or worker processes (which are not shared memory at all).  So you definitely can't write to the array directly using that package.  What you are describing is more fine-grained than the standard R parallelization tools, so I suspect you will not get a satisfactory solution.  Maybe someone else knows something I don't, though.

Comment: If you have C++ code why do you want to slow it down by translating it to R? Just call the C++ function from R, i.e., use Rcpp.

Comment: That is an option, but I really wanted to know if R also had these capabilities in some way.  Even if I couldn't do it with global variables, I just wanted some ideas on how the same thing could potentially be done in parallel and if possible via recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be difficult to translate OpenMP programs to R since R isn't multi-threaded. In your case, the different threads are writing to different variables, so it's pretty easy. You just have to initialize the workers properly and remember to return the result variable after calling the recursive function. It won't perform well compared to the C++ version, but you already understand that.

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(4)

# Create "p" and "recurComp" on each of the workers
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  p <- double(length=5 + 1)
  recurComp <- function(n, nWB, prob, nGB) {
    if (n == 1){
      p[nGB] <<- prob
      return(NULL)
    }
    if(nWB == 4){
      recurComp(n - 1, 3, .8*prob, nGB)
      nGB <- nGB + 1
      recurComp(n - 1, 4, .2*prob, nGB)
    }
    if(nWB == 3){
      recurComp(n - 1, 2, .75*prob, nGB)
      nGB <- nGB + 1
      recurComp(n - 1, 4, .25*prob, nGB)
    }
    if(nWB == 2){
      recurComp(n - 1, 1, (2./3.)*prob, nGB)
      nGB <- nGB + 1
      recurComp(n - 1, 4, (1/3.)*prob, nGB)
    }
    if(nWB == 1){
      recurComp(n - 1, 0, .5*prob, nGB)
      nGB <- nGB + 1
      recurComp(n - 1, 4, .5*prob, nGB)
    }
    if(nWB == 0){
      nGB <- nGB + 1
      recurComp(n - 1, 4, prob, nGB)
    }
    return(NULL)
  }
  NULL
})

worker <- function(n, nWB, prob, nGB) {
  recurComp(n, nWB, prob, nGB)
  p
}

# Perform the recursive computation.  This assumes that
# the number of tasks is equal to the number of workers.
plist <- clusterMap(cl, worker,
                    n=c(5-1,5-1,5-1,5-1),
                    nWB=c(4,3,4,2),
                    prob=c(.2*.2,.2*.8,.8*.25,.8*.75),
                    nGB=c(2,1,1,0))
```

Note that since the output variables aren't shared by the workers, they're called "p" on each of the workers which simplifies the code.